# Where should I post follow-up questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

I recently posted a question that quite promptly got a number of decent answers. One of those answers led me to a closely related but slightly different question. What's the best way to bring up that additional question? I could..

- ask the new question in an "answer" to my original question (this is what I did, but it's kind of colder and, I suspect, less likely to be seen by people),
- edit my original question to include the second one,
- or post a new question.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you make this a community-wiki question?  I think it'd be a good part of the FAQ.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-related-questions-arising-after-i-get-answers

Answer (score 14):

Ask new question and include a link to the related one.

Answer (score 14):

You can post a new question with a link to the old question.

Comment: Also posting (as a comment) a link to the new question on the old question is useful.

Answer (score 5):

Post the new question and refer (link) to the old one. If you edit the original, it may dissappear down the tube as it is "old" and you may not get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new question, and link to the previous question.

It's disrespectful to those who answered your original question because you risk their answers getting downvoted now that their answers don't sync with the question.  There isn't a limit of questions that I'm aware of, but multiple questions is also good for you because you'd get +2 rep for every question answered.

Answer (score 2):

If it is really still one question, amend the original question.  If it is really a new question, albeit related to the previous question, ask a new question and link back to the original.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how closely your new question is related.

The idea of stackoverflow is to be a wiki of ideas, so if it's close to your original question, go ahead and edit the question.  Someone with enough reputation can add the answer to that part to the best answer.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044/good-free-alternative-to-ms-access) is what I did when I had a situation like that.  I'm specifically referring to the "See Also" part.