# What's the policy on follow up questions?

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should I post follow-up questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-follow-up-questions)

I'm used to asking questions on internet forums where after asking the question and getting some answers the OP can ask some follow up questions or even slightly change the topic (but not much). Here, however it's not possible - I get to only ask 1 question and that's it. What is the correct way to ask a follow up question here (at stackoverflow)? Ask it in comment? Create another question (thread) and provide a link to the previous one (as they're connected)?

Comment: Simply put it's okay. Create a new question, add a link to the old one but ensure that your second question is understandable on it's own without reference to the old one.

Answer (score 8):

> I get to only ask 1 question and that's it.

Says who? The "Ask Question" button doesn't disappear just because you asked a question. You ask a *new* question.

We don't allow threaded back-and-forth dithering over questions and answers. You ask a question, it gets answered. If that precipitates another question (rather than just a request for clarification), then you ask a *new* question. You don't get to hide a question within some other question.

Comment: "rather than just a request for clarification" and where would I put that? In a comment?

Comment: @NPS: Yes, that's what comments are for.